# Can I use "or" in a condition inside a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Is there a way to put an "or" inside a condition that it's in a list comprehension?
I would like to "compress" this block of code:

```
# In this lines of code I take a certain text_file.txt and create a list with each word, without 
# considering the lines that starts with "#" OR empty lines
for line in text_file:
    if not line.startswith("#") or line != "\n":
       word_list = ([word for word in line.split()])
```

So I thought that this could be done:

```
[[word for word in line.split()] for line in text_file if not line.startswith("#") or line != "\n"]
```

Of course the code up there doesn't return the output I am expecting.

Is there a way to make something like the hypothetical list comprhension that I wrote up there?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this? 'if (not line.startswith("#") or line != "\n")'

Comment: This `[word for word in line.split()]` is unnecessary. You can just use `line.split()`

Comment: @Karl That changes the logic. Only the first condition should have the `not` applied to it.

Comment: that was a typo sorry

Comment: Your condition seems backwards. If the line does not start with "#", then the second condition isn't considered. If the line *does* start with "#", it then checks whether it's not "\n", which is obviously always true, since it's already proven that it starts with "#". You probably want `and`, not `or`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use 'or' within list comprehensions, try:

```
mylist  = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print([i for i in mylist if i >6 or i <3])
>>>[1, 2, 7, 8, 9]
```

the problem in your code is that you use 'or' but should use 'and':

```
mylist  = ["1 2 3","2 3 4","\n","1 2 4","#somecomment"]
print([i.split(" ") for i in mylist if i[0] !="#" and i !="\n"])
>>>[['1', '2', '3'], ['2', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '4']]
```